# Prove that $\frac{1}{abc}+36\ge \frac{21}{ab+bc+ca}$

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method, uvw, buffalo-way

If $a+b+c=1$ and $a,b,c>0$ then prove that $$\frac{1}{abc}+36\ge \frac{21}{ab+bc+ca}$$

My try : We have to prove: $$ab+bc+ca+36abc(ab+bc+ca)\ge 21abc$$ or after homogenising we get :
$$\sum a^4b+3\sum a^3b^2+6\sum a^2b^2c\ge 14\sum a^3bc$$
I don't know what to do next. I think SOS may be helpful but find it difficult to factorize. Any other methods are also welcome but, if possible, can someone help me continue from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4b+a^4c-a^3b^2-a^3c^2)+4\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^2+a^3c^2-2a^3bc)-6\sum_{cyc}(a^3bc-a^2b^2c)\geq0$$ or

$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4b-a^3b^2-a^2b^3+ab^4)+$$
$$+4\sum_{cyc}(c^3a^2+c^3b^2-2c^3bc)-3abc\sum_{cyc}(a^2+b^2-2ab)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(ab(a+b)+4c^3-3abc)\geq0,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$ab(a+b)+4c^3\geq2\sqrt{a^3b^3}+c^3\geq3\sqrt[3]{a^3b^3c^3}=3abc$$
The following inequality a bit of stronger.

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers such that $a+b+c=1$. Prove that:
> $$\frac{1}{abc}+48\geq\frac{25}{ab+ac+bc}.$$

Comment: sir, could you explain a little bit more on how you factorised in the second step I am not able to follow that.

Comment: @Quantum I added something. I hope now it's clear.

Comment: yes i got it ,( i always find it dfficult to factorise in inequalities ) thank you for your time,

Comment: @Quantum You are welcome!

Comment: The last is very known =))

Comment: @nguyenhuyen_ag I think something very similar was in one of Russian's contests. Maybe in 2006 or in 2005 or even in 2002. The reasoning in the official solution was very similar to $uvw$. I found this fact few years ago.

Comment: Dear Sir, Yes, it's an old problem in Kvant magazine.

Comment: $48$ is the best constant here.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $t = \frac{a+b}{2}$ and $c = \max \{a,b,c\}.$ Let
$$f(a,b,c) = \frac{1}{abc}+36 - \frac{21}{ab+bc+ca}.$$
We have
$$f(a,b,c) -f(t,t,c) = \frac{1}{abc}-\frac{4}{c(a+b)^2}+\frac{84}{(a+b)(a+b+4c)}-\frac{21}{ab+bc+ca}$$
$$ = \frac{(a-b)^2}{a+b}\left(\frac{1}{abc(a+b)}-\frac{21}{(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+4c)}\right) \geqslant 0,$$
because
$$(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+4c)=(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+4c) $$
$$ \geqslant 9abc (a+b+4c) > 21abc(a+b).$$
Thefore
$$f(a,b,c) \geqslant f(t,t,c) = f\left(\frac{1-c}{2},\frac{1-c}{2},c\right)=\frac{4(3c^2-3c+1)(3c-1)^2}{c(3c+1)(c-1)^2} \geqslant 0.$$
The proof is completed.

Comment: is there any name for this method "?

Comment: Hi @Quantum, it's called `mixing variables` method

Comment: Thank you i didnt know about it.

Comment: Hi @Quantum, It's very strong method, you can read in Secrets in Inequalities volume 2.

Comment: thanks! i am currently doing its  volume 1

Comment: and do you by chance know a good book on inequalities that goes from basic to advanced(gradually) with lots of practice problems.   in  secrets in ineq.  it starts of with really hard olympiad problems

Comment: I am not sure English book but you can learn the theory in Secrets in Inequalities vol 1 as AM-GM, Cauchy-Schwarz, Holder, ... and find some exercises in seri Mathematical Inequalities of Vasile Cirtoaje. Moreover, you can search the post of members on AoPS as Vasc, can_hang2007, arqady, quykhtn-qa1, ... they are masters of inequality

Comment: thanks for advice

Comment: @nguyenhuyen_ag you are master as SOS also :D

Comment: @nguyenhuyen_ag Vasile Cirtoaje's books are far more difficult. It has more difficult factorizations, but one thing good is that the proofs are descriptive and elegant. I think the first 25 problems are enough a school student.

Comment: @BookOfFlames Yes, all most the proof in the book are very simple and beautiful but it's not easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the shortest way here it's using $uvw$.

Indeed, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that $f(w^3)\geq0,$ where
$$f(w^3)=\frac{3u^3}{w^3}+4-\frac{7u^2}{v^2}.$$
Now we see that $f$ decreases, which says that it's enough to prove our inequality for a maximal value of $w^3$, which by $uvw$ happens for equality case of two variables.

We could have seen it before because the starting inequality it's a polynomial symmetric inequality of fifth degree.

Now, after homogenization we need to prove that:
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{abc}+36\geq\frac{21(a+b+c)^2}{ab+ac+bc}.$$
Since the last inequality is homogeneous and symmetric, it's enough to assume $b=c=1$, which gives:
$$(a-1)^2(a^2-2a+4)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I found another SOS proof$:$

After homogenising the inequality become$:$
$$a \left( b-c \right) ^{4}+b \left( c-a\right) ^{4}+c \left( a-b
 \right) ^{4}+3\,{a}^{3} \left( b-c \right) ^{2}+3\,{b}^{3} \left( c-a \right) ^{2}+3\,{c}^{3} \left( a-b \right) ^{2}\geqslant 0$$

Or another SOS$:$ $$\sum  \left( {a}^{2}b+a{b}^{2}-6\,abc+3\,{c}^{2}a+3\,{c}^{2}b+{c}^{3}
 \right)  \left( a-b \right) ^{2}\geqslant 0$$

which is easy to prove$:$ $$ {a}^{2}b+a{b}^{2}-6\,abc+3\,{c}^{2}a+3\,{c}^{2}b+{c}^{3}
  \geqslant 0.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: can you explain a bit more on how you got the second step (factorisation)

Comment: @Quantum I use same way as Mr. Mike. With attention $\sum G(a,b,c)(a-c)(b-c)(a-b)^2=0$ where $G(a,b,c)$ are symmetric between $a,b.$

Comment: then shouldnt it be $\sum{(a-b)}^2{(c{(a-b)}^2+3c^3)}$

Comment: @Quantum what do you mean$?$ (+1 me and all helping people if their help is ok)

Comment: i have upvoted all , the answers

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

Let $a=\min\{a,b,c\},$ $b=a+u$ and $c=a+v$.

Thus, $u\geq0$, $v\geq0$ and
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4b+a^4c+3a^3b^2+3a^3c^2-14a^3bc+6a^2b^2c^2)=$$
$$=6(u^2-uv+v^2)a^3+9uv(u+v)a^2+$$
$$+2(u^4-2u^3v+12u^2v^2-2uv^3+v^4)a+uv(u+v)^3\geq0.$$